# How to recreate auto-collapasable menu with semantic-ui for react?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, menu, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Original [semantic-ui menu](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html) does auto turn into a hamburger icon

[image]

seems like via code duplication. Is it possible to recreate it in [semantic-ui-react](https://react.semantic-ui.com/introduction) with out code duplication (as one component) and how to do such thing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Neither Semantic UI, nor Semantic UI React have a responsive NavBar. However, I want to implement it as add-on for Semantic UI React in near future.

At the current moment, you can implement it using `Menu` and `Sidebar` components. It will allow you to avoid code and markup duplication.

I've made a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/325y47xk36) that shows how to do this.

Comment: No expectations but just wondering if you have updated code for this codepen.  Thanks.

Comment: Very elegant and great solution! Thanks!

Comment: The sandbox is broken for me

Comment: Folks, I updated a CodeSandbox, it runs on SUIR v2, I also replaced deprecated `Responsive` component 